# I just want to insert a picture into my html page?

Tags: html

Sorry, but I am very frustrated, I just want to insert a picture into my website.

```
<img src="example.jpg" alt="Example"/>
```

The file is in the same directory as the html.

What is wrong with that????????????

file tree:

[image]

Still it does not work :(

Edit:
./example.jpg does not work either ! :(

[image]

It just shows the alt... :(

Edit:
Seems like the problem comes from the CS50 IDE! I will try to upload the image to another website and then acces it :/

Comment: please share your file tree

Comment: and is `example.jpg` directly inside the same directory as the html, or is example.jpg is inside an another dir like img?

Comment: The tag is correct, your path is probably wrong

Comment: "./example.jpg"  try this. 
Most IDE's show autocompletions then you see if you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The tag is correct, but make sure that `Example.jpg` is in the same exact folder as the html file and check the file name and its extension too (it's case sensetive)

Answer (score 0):

Bro, first check if the image you want is really on the same folder you're working on it and then:

```
<img src="./example.jpg" alt="Example" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="./example.jpg" alt="Example" />
```

you can also use picture tag in html like:

```
 <picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="./example.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="./example01.jpg">
  <img src="./example02.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

or you can have a simple `div` and add the picture using css like:

```
div {
  background-image: url(./example.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh; //change it to what you like
  width: 100vw; //change it to what you like
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not think that the picture or div tags will lead to the solution. It does not work either. It has to be sth with the file tree, but I do not know what. I also tried the absolute pos, i.e. http etc. but it does not work too

Comment: @MarcoP. there might also be some elements that cover your image or some js might be included that hidden the picrute. use the inspect tool of your browser and see for yourself. you might have the picture but cannot just see it.